# Move markers using mouse in angular google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I am doing an angular project.It contains a google map using [angular-google-maps](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/).So on this map,the user can add many `markers`.

**app.js**

```
angular.module('mapAngular', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        angular.extend($scope, {
            map: {
                center: {
                    latitude: 42.3349940452867,
                    longitude: -71.0353168884369
                },
                zoom: 11,
                markers: [],
                events: {
                    click: function(map, eventName, originalEventArgs) {
                        var e = originalEventArgs[0];
                        var lat = e.latLng.lat(),
                            lon = e.latLng.lng();
                        var marker = {
                            id: Date.now(),
                            coords: {
                                latitude: lat,
                                longitude: lon
                            }
                        };
                        $scope.map.markers.push(marker);
                        console.log($scope.map.markers);
                        $scope.$apply();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" events="map.events">
        <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="m in map.markers" coords="m.coords" icon="m.icon" idkey="m.id"></ui-gmap-marker>
    </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

The map will shows all added markers.I need a feature to move this markers dynamically by using mouse.Please give me a valuable guideline to this?
Thanks

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iQrSobJIu41MpZgS4YRi?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue by giving `options="{draggable:true}"` in to `<ui-gmap-marker>` directive.

```
<ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="m in map.markers" coords="m.coords" icon="m.icon" idkey="m.id" options="{draggable:true}" >
</ui-gmap-marker>
```